# Is there a difference in speed between sending a texture atlas vs single images to the GPU?

Tags: java, opengl, gpu

I am making a game which has an extensible number of textures, using OpenGL for rendering.

Is there a (significant/noticeable) difference in rendering/processing speed between:

- Stitching all of the images into one "atlas", sending the buffer to the GPU, and then drawing a small section of that atlas when I need to draw a tile.
- Sending each image buffer separately and maintain a map of handles for each image

The former seems to be the more widely used option? (That I have seen?) ... But the latter seems to be easier to program, as I would not have to stitch all of the images together.

Note: space taken by images in memory is not my concern here, though if there is a difference there then I'd be glad to know it.

Comment: the GPU does not need to bind textures when rendering with a texture atlas.

Comment: texture atlas needs less GL calls so its faster ... in new OpenGL there is bindless texturing which achieves the same rendering performance as texture atlas however the init is still slower due to more gl calls needed while loading the textures into GPU. As the init is usually done just once or few times per many frames this overhead is negligible unless we talking about thousands of textures. You can compare it to the difference between `glBegin/glEnd` and `VBO/VAO` ... the more GL calls per the same amount of work is less efficient